How to add an interval to a tsrange?
I tried this:
select
  tsrange(now()::timestamp,
          now()::timestamp + make_interval(days => 3))
  + make_interval(mins => 5);

But I get the error that tsrange + interval does not exist.

Such an operator probably doesn't exist because it is a very unusual operation.

The operation is more like shifting for an interval rather than adding

@LaurenzAlbe Unusual? Programming languages have been invented just to perform element-wise arithmetic: Matlab. When you move a meeting taking 3 hours from 9 o'clock to 10 o'clock, you perform exactly this "unusual" operation.

Well, relational databases typically are not into vector arithmetic... and it is a stretch to see a range as a two-dimensional vector. But all I wanted to do was explain why there is no ready-made solution. You for some good answers how to deal with the problem.

To resolve your issue, I did the following (all of the code above is available on the fiddle here):
CREATE TABLE test
(
  tsr TSTZRANGE
);

a record:
INSERT INTO test (tsr) VALUES
('[2024-04-09 09:04:00, 2024-04-09 09:07:00]'::TSTZRANGE);

and then we run:
SELECT
  (
    '[' 
      || (LOWER(tsr) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH')::TEXT || ', '
      || (UPPER(tsr) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH')::TEXT || 
    ']'
  )::TSTZRANGE AS range_plus
FROM
  test;

Result:
range_plus
["2024-05-09 09:04:00+00","2024-05-09 09:07:00+00"]

Note the use of the PG_TYPEOF() function in the fiddle - it helps with debugging - can be easy to get lost in all of the commas, parentheses, braces and brackets!
You can change this into a function using PL/pgSQL as follows:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  range_add(i_range TSTZRANGE, i_intv INTERVAL)
RETURNS TSTZRANGE
LANGUAGE SQL AS 
$FUNC$
 
SELECT
  (
    '[' 
      || (LOWER(i_range) + i_intv)::TEXT || ', '
      || (UPPER(i_range) + i_intv)::TEXT || 
    ']'
  )::TSTZRANGE  

$FUNC$;

and to test:
SELECT
  range_add(tsr, '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL)
FROM
  test;

Result - the same as above, see fiddle! +1 - this would make a nice extension and a good suggestion for ulimate integration into core. I found this answer helpful.
In order to add 2 intervals (one to the lower bound of the range, the other to the upper bound), you can do the following (see comments from OP) - extended fiddle:
New function:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  range_add_2(i_range TSTZRANGE, i_intv_low_add INTERVAL, i_intv_up_add INTERVAL)
RETURNS TSTZRANGE
LANGUAGE SQL AS 
$FUNC$
 
SELECT
  (
    '[' 
      || (LOWER($1) + $2)::TEXT || ', '
      || (UPPER($1) + $3)::TEXT || 
    ']'
  )::TSTZRANGE  
$FUNC$;

and test:
WITH cte AS
(  
  SELECT
    ('[' || NOW()::TEXT || ',' || (NOW() + '1 YEAR'::INTERVAL)::TEXT || ')')::TSTZRANGE
    AS tr
)
SELECT 
  RANGE_ADD_2(tr, '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL, '2 MONTHS'::INTERVAL)
FROM
  cte;

Result:
range_add_2
["2024-05-09 11:44:18.134196+00","2025-06-09 11:44:18.134196+00"]

Et voilà!

I am wondering why something basic like this requires a function.

@ceving - is my answer incomplete in some way? It could be modified to include 2 intervals - the logic becomes exponentially more complex - for example with checks that LOWER(range) is not greater than UPPER(range) after additions inter alia.

It works but if I write a function I would prefer just tzrange(lower(r)+i,upper(r)+i).

@ceving - Please see extended answer.

Not sure if I get it right, but you can create an interval by subtracting two timestamps:
select (now()::timestamp 
           + make_interval(days => 3) 
           + make_interval(mins => 5)
       ) - now()::timestamp;

Fiddle

My aim is to shift a tsrange: move a duration of 3 days 5 minutes into the future. The return value of your expression is not tsrange but interval.
